# How to change the color of tab icons

Tags: maui

As you can see I have added in FlyoutItem the Tabs that have Icon property which is an svg image that I need to change the color

```
    <FlyoutItem FlyoutDisplayOptions="AsMultipleItems" >
            <Tab Title="Inicio" Icon="housesolid.svg">
                <ShellContent  ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:LoginCameraQR}"  />
            </Tab>
            <Tab Title="Perfil" Icon="usergroupsolid.svg">
                <ShellContent  ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:LoginCameraQR}"  />
            </Tab>
            <Tab Title="Cupones" Icon="tagssolid.svg">
                <ShellContent  ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:LoginCameraQR}"  />
            </Tab>
            <Tab Title="Favoritos" Icon="heartsolid.svg">
                <ShellContent  ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:LoginCameraQR}"   />
            </Tab>
        <Tab  Title="Acerca de Nosotros" >
            <ShellContent  ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:LoginCameraQR}"   />
        </Tab>
        <Tab Title="Facebook" Icon="facebook.svg">
            <ShellContent  ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:LoginCameraQR}"   />
        </Tab>
        <Tab Title="Instagram" Icon="squareinstagram.svg">
            <ShellContent  ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:LoginCameraQR}"   />
        </Tab>
    </FlyoutItem>
```

And I want to change the color of these svg icons, any ideas?

[image]

I tried with style, but it did not work, the property is not valid

```
    <Style TargetType="Tab" Class="FlyoutItemImageStyle">
            <Setter Property="Background"  
            Value="AliceBlue"></Setter>
        </Style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another approach in order to change the tab icon colors, or even to change the actual icon to another or even for example to have a bigger icon when the tab is selected is to use events.

At your AppShell.xaml name the tabs as needed (tabHome, tabAbout etc).

```
<Tab Icon="{StaticResource LogoIcon}" x:Name="tabHome">
    <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate pages:HomePage}"/>
</Tab>
<Tab Icon="{StaticResource AboutIcon}" x:Name="tabAbout">
    <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate pages:AboutPage}"/>
</Tab>
```

At your code behind AppShell.xaml.cs register the event. You will have to add as staticresource two icons. One normal for the unselected tab and one for the highlighted tab.

```
public AppShell()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   BindingContext = this;

   WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Register<string>(this, (r, m) =>
   {
      //note here that your dictionary may not be the last as the example
      var res = Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Last() as ResourceDictionary;
            
      if (m.ToLower() == "homepage")
      {
           var icon = (ImageSource)res["LogoHighlightIcon"];
           tabHome.Icon = icon;
       }
       else
       {
           var icon = (ImageSource)res["LogoIcon"];
           tabHome.Icon = icon;
       }
      
       // do the same as above for all tabs
   }
}
```

At the end, raise the event at OnAppearing e.g. at HomePage.xaml.cs at each page you want to change the tab icon.

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();

    WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Send("HomePage");
}
```

So, the idea is that when the tab is selected, an event is triggered, and the icon changes. The rest of the icons will return to default state.

Hope that helps others with the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to set the TintColor of the svg Image. You could just set the TintColor for the Image in csproj file:

```
<MauiImage Include="Resources\Images\housesolid.svg" TintColor="#66B3FF" />
```

Hope it works for you.